# AWS serverless and javascript - is it secure?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, serverless

So I am digging into the 'serverless' architecture and after going over a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/building-serverless-apps-with-aws-lambda) about angular as front-end and nodejs lambdas available by an API I am not sure if it is secure at all. The angular website that I did makes calls to AWS api which is linked to lambda function. Because it is angular and it is  visible to the client's browser, important secret keys such as -  AWSCognito.config.update({accessKeyId: 'something', secretAccessKey: 'something'}); can be seen.

When creating those keys, AWS lets you see them once and then hides the secretAccessKey so I guess it is not quite reasonable to leave it in a js file? I am still learning the fundamentals of AWS so let me know what do you think and what is the best solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Because it is javascript and it is all visible to the client

That isn't true.

JavaScript is a programming language.

JavaScript you send to the browser to run on the browser is visible to the owner of the browser. You seem to be conflating this with "All JavaScript".

JavaScript you send to AWS to run on AWS is not visible to the owner of the browser.

Comment: Also, for further reading: search about "server-side JavaScript" and "NodeJS".

Comment: Right, my bad. For this particular example I am talking about having a nodejs lambdas and API linked to them that is consumed by angular website. In order to make the calls to the api you have to pass aws secret key and I am currently doing that in an angular js file - running on the client browser.

Comment: @user3873146 — You should use AWS API Gateway as a frontend around your Lambda, and configure the API Gateway to not need to receive an API key.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for that suggestion but then is there a way to prevent someone brute forcing the post request? It is a simple http post call that saves subscriber's emails to dynamodb using lambda.